# Can I restore a Ghost image of a Mac Mini onto a PC or laptop?

Tags: mac, disk-image, intel-core2, ghost

Can I make a Ghost image of a Mac Mini and restore it on my Dell 630 Latitude? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A regular PC or laptop cannot run OS X out of the box.

Installing OS X on Windows is against the OS X EULA. You may only run OS X on Apple hardware. While this doesn't imply that it's technically impossible, it is not supported, and requires special hardware.

Plus, it probably requires a special "cracked" version of the OS X installer – so you cannot take an existing OS X installation and migrate it to a PC.